# How to GET Job ID in perform action in activejob (adapter=resque) in Rails

Tags: redis, resque, rails-activejob

I can get the JOB ID from before_enqueue method
e.g.

```
before_enqueue do |job|
  puts "Before Enqueu JOB ID: #{job.job_id}"
end
```

BUT I want to get it also in perform method
Please Help!

Comment: fixed!
in def perform method (I used self.job_id)